# Tracking COM object error in application

Tags: com, win32com, win32ole

I was using an application and it was working perfect. After some months of not using it, I tried to run it and it doesn't work. It shows a message box saying that it cannot instance a COM object.

Do any know how to track errors in COM objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ProcessMonitor and try to find the registry key that may be incorrect.
The other option is to use http://www.moduleanalyzer.com, it intercepts CoCreateInstance showing all created COM objects and the return values.

Comment: I tried ProcessMonitor but really I didn't understand how it can help me. I watched the registry keys and everything seems ok. The problem was detected by module analyzer that showed my a COM error that I was able to fix registering again a dll. It looks like a new version of an object was installed and the old application was asking for the old interface that it is no longer valid for the object. After registering the correct object the application runs smoothly!

Answer (score 1):

Run Depends tool on COM object DLL to verify it has all the necessary dlls, re-register the COM dll/exe.

Any HRESULTS from debugging/logs? Any changes in apartment models?

You cannot change the apartment type once you've set one. So if the object cannot use one of the models and you try to CoCreate it, it will fail. That's why you never call CoInit from inside DLL main thread.

Comment: DebugView doesn't show any error. Yes, I understand that CoCreate will fail in that circumstances but I want to know which object failed the CoCreateInstance.